# How does YUM know of a software update of something I installed from a CD or download

Tags: linux, yum

Can YUM update software that I install from a CD? Let's say I install open office, run an installer. How is YUM aware of the location, updates for that software?

thanks

Comment: Not sure if YUM can detect CD installs, but according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) article YUM is a package-manager for **RPM-based** distributions. Stands to reason that YUM does keep a log of sorts, at least from the repositories it has access.